# Cambiar el formato de fecha de Epoch a datetime en PowerShell

Tags: datetime, powershell, formato

Tengo un String que representa un tiempo en Epoch y necesito el formato correcto para poderlo introducir en una base de datos SQL Server, desde PowerShell. 
Hasta ahora puedo cambiar el formato Epoch a un formato de fecha muy larga, EJEMPLO:

Fecha en Epoch a convertir:  `746181000`

Funcion que utilizo:

```
[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds('746181000'))
```

El output es el siguiente:

```
Tuesday, August 24, 1993 3:30:00 AM
```

Lo que realmente necesito es la fecha en este formato: `yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:ss`

Por lo que mi output deseado seria `1993-08-24 03:30:00`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

Según la función que defines anteriormente:

```
[timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds('746181000'))
```

Puedes usar el comando [Get-Date](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6) junto al parámetro ***Format*** para manipular la salida según tu necesidad, de la siguiente manera:

```
$epochOut = [timezone]::CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(([datetime]'1/1/1970').AddSeconds('746181000'))
$outputFixed = $epochOut | Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"
```